# Module not found: Can't resolve '

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display a few words from a react js project in Visual studio code and I have an error.
In App.js component I imported a css document and this thing cause an display error on the page:

Module not found: Can't resolve './appStyles.css' in 'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\React\hello-world\src'

This is the code from App.js component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'
import Greet from './components/Greet'
import Welcome from './components/Welcome'
import Hello from './components/Hello'
import Message from './components/Message'
import Counter from './components/Counter'
import FunctionClick from './components/FunctionClick'
import ClassClick from './components/ClassClick'
import EventBind from './components/EventBind'
import ParentComponent from './components/ParentComponent'
import UserGreeting from './components/UserGreeting'
import NameList from './components/NameList'
import Stylesheet from './components/Stylesheet'
import Inline from './components/Inline'
import './appStyles.css'
import styles from './appStyles.module.css'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div className="App">
     <h1 className='error'>Error</h1>
     <h1 className={styles.success}>Success</h1>
     <Inline /> 
     {/*<Stylesheet primary={true} /> */}
     {/*<NameList /> */}
     {/*<UserGreeting /> */}
     {/* <EventBind /> */}
     {/*<ParentComponent /> */}
     { /*<FunctionClick /> */}
     { /*<ClassClick /> */}
      { /*<Counter /> */}
       { /*<Message /> */}
       {/*<Greet name="Bruce" heroName="Batman">
        <p>This is children props</p>
        </Greet>
        <Greet name="Clark" heroName="Superman">
         <button>Action</button>
        </Greet> */}
        {/*<Greet name="Diana" heroName="Wonder Woman" />
        <Welcome name="Bruce" heroName="Batman" /> */} 
        {/*<Welcome name="Clark" heroName="Superman" />
        <Welcome name="Diana" heroName="Wonder Woman" /> */}
        {/*<Hello /> */}
     </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Folder Structure:

[image]

Comment: Is the error message not clear or what kind of help are you looking for?

Comment: Do you have a file called `appStyles.css` in the `src` folder inside your project directory ? If not remove the import `import './appStyles.css'`, which should resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of the folder structure of your app where we can see appStyles.css and app.js both?

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Change `import` statement to

```
import './components/appStyles.css';
import styles from './components/appStyles.module.css';
```

**Explaination:**

---

- Your `app.js` is inside => `src/app.js`
- Your `appStyles.css` is inside => `src/components/appStyles.css`
- That's why import statement should be => `import './components/appStyles.css'`

---

Comment: I understood the explanation, I made the suggested change and now I get the error like this:./src/App.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '.components/appStyles.css' in 'C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\React\hello-world\src'

Comment: How you changed it? Like this or `.components/appStyles.css` OR `./components/appStyles.css`

Comment: I wrote like this: .components/appStyles.css and now I corrected like this: ./components/appStyles.css but and now it appear another error:  src\App.js
  Line 25:21:  'styles' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: `import styles from './components/appStyles.module.css';
` include this line too.

Comment: I added and now it works fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Alex1 Cheer! Please upvote and accept this answer if it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

That errors means your `.css` file is not in the path that you put it.
You can put a screenshot of your folders and let us help you.

After your photo you need it to be imported like:
`import './components/appStyles.css'`.

Also for your second imported style you need to do the same, otherwise will not work because both are in `components` folder.

As a piece of advice, you can create another folder to structure your project better, like: `Styles` and put all your `.css` files in there.